# Buttons in vertical layout in QDialog with return value

Tags: qt

I want to create a QDialog with Qt that looks somewhat like this:
[image]
The desired properties here are:

- I can add a text to the dialog explaining the question behind it
- I can add several buttons that are in a vertical layout
- I can retrieve the value of the clicked button, i.e. I know if the user cancelled or clicked 1, 2 or 3 - ideally I can emit a signal with the corresponding value as parameter.
- The dialog has a certain minimum height and width.

I have used a QMessageBox before for this purpose, but I can't get it to use a vertical layout. I have experimented with a QDialogButtonBox and a QDialog, but I can't really figure out how to get my desired return value easily. 
A piece of code creating this dialog with code how to retrieve the clicked value would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a QDialog widget? you can add QDialog without buttons to your project. In UI designer, add Vertical layout, label, and buttons.
In your class define your signals and emit it when the user clicked on buttons.

[image: Sample a Dialog UI]

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your reply! So I need to define a signal and a slot for each button? I was hoping for something like the "clickedButton" function of the QMessageBox.